# Access: Undefined Function "Right" in Expression

Tags: ms-access

With Microsoft Access 2016 I am making some new linkages to tables in MariaDB. While testing the queries after making these new linkages I am coming across error such as this one: "Undefined function "Right" in expression".

From the research I've done, this is usually not an issue with the SQL syntax itself, but rather a glitch in Access. People have suggested looking going to "Tools > References" and looking for anything listed as "Missing".

Within the Access 2016 interface I don't see any such "Tools" menu. How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be in the vba code editor to see the tools menu.  Press the F11 key to open up the access object window.  Then go to the Modules section and double click on a module.  This will open the vba editor where you'll see the tools menu.